# Assign a value based on closest neighbour from other data frame

Tags: r, data.table, dplyr

With generic data:

```
set.seed(456)

a <- sample(0:1,50,replace = T)
b <- rnorm(50,15,5)
df1 <- data.frame(a,b)

c <- seq(0.01,0.99,0.01)
d <- rep(NA, 99)
for (i in 1:99) {
  d[i] <- 0.5*(10*c[i])^2+5
}
df2 <- data.frame(c,d)
```

For each `df1$b` we want to find the nearest `df2$d`. 
Then we create a new variable `df1$XYZ` that takes the `df2$c` value of the nearest `df2$d`

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19957725/r-assign-column-value-based-on-closest-match-in-second-data-frame) has guided me towards `data.table` library. But I am not sure if `ddplyr` and `group_by` can also be used:

Here was my `data.table` attempt:

```
library(data.table)
dt1 <- data.table( df1 , key = "b" )
dt2 <- data.table( df2 , key = "d" )

dt[ ldt , list( d ) , roll = "nearest" ]
```

Comment: I havn't tested, but maybe just `setDT(df1)[df2, XYZ := i.c, on = c(b = "d"), roll = "nearest"]`?

Comment: How about reading [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20133344/find-closest-value-in-a-vector-with-binary-search)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's one way with `data.table`:

```
require(data.table)
setDT(df1)[, XYZ := setDT(df2)[df1, c, on=c(d="b"), roll="nearest"]]
```

You need to get `df2$c` corresponding to the nearest value in `df2$d` for every `df1$b`. So, we need to join as `df2[df1]` which results in `nrow(df1)` rows.That can be done with `setDT(df2)[df1, c, on=c(d="b"), roll="nearest"]`.

It returns the result you require. All we need to do is to add this back to `df1` with the name `XYZ`. We do that using `:=`.

---

The thought process in constructing the *rolling join* is something like this (assuming `df1` and `df2` are both data tables):

1. We need get some value(s) for each row of `df1`. That means, `i = df1` in `x[i]` syntax.

   ```
   df2[df1]
   ```
2. We need to join `df2$d` with `df1$b`. Using `on=` that'd be:

   ```
   df2[df1, on=c(d="b")]
   ```
3. We need just the `c` column. Use `j` to select just that column.

   ```
   df2[df1, c, on=c(d="b")]
   ```
4. We don't need *equi-join* but *roll to nearest* join.

   ```
   df2[df1, c, on=c(d="b"), roll="nearest"]
   ```

Hope this helps.